# C# get a value from script using WebRequest

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I need to get a value from script in Webrequest's response. The code is like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var CUS = CUS || {};
        CUS.namespace('CUS.model');
        CUS.model.page = {"Key":"needed Value"};
<script>
```

I can deserialize that json if i get, Is there any nice using for this getting process?

Edit : Let me try to complain; I get a response from a HttpWebRequest and its a html document like below

```
string result; 

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument(); 
document.LoadHtml(result);
```

"result" variable have :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var CUS = CUS || {}; 
       CUS.namespace('CUS.model');
       CUS.model.page = {"Key":"needed Value"}//It seems like json!; 
    <script>
```

I need to get after the "CUS.model.page =" thing.

Comment: webrequest doesn't have a javascript engine

Comment: @JaromandaX but its a reponse and its string. i need to read, {"Key":"needed Value"} value from a string result.

Comment: Please clarify. I don't see any json, nor any request. Start from the beginning, what are you doing, what are you getting and what exactly is the result you want?

Comment: Hello @Crowcoder. 

Let me try to complain; I get a response from a HttpWebRequest and its a html document like below 

`string result;

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            document.LoadHtml(result); `

"result" variable have :

`<script type="text/javascript">
        var CUS = CUS || {};
        CUS.namespace('CUS.model');
        CUS.model.page = {"Key":"needed Value"};
<script>`

I need to get after the "CUS.model.page =" thing.

Comment: oh, right, your use of the phrase JSON confused me

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to extract the key.

```
string result = @"
<script type=""text/javascript"">
    var CUS = CUS || {}; 
    CUS.namespace('CUS.model');
    CUS.model.page = {""Key"":""needed Value""}//It seems like json!; 
<script>";

Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"(CUS\.model\.page\s*=\s*)({""Key"":"")(.*)(""})");
string key = match.Success ? match.Groups[3].Value : null;
```

You can adapt the regular expression to make it more robust, in case the content in the script tag changes in the future.